# Can I call a php file on form submit, and call or echo a JS function from that?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I'm basically trying to create an HTML form that will

1. process my login through php POST method
2. close my login lighbox with javascript, or display an error (right now I'm using JS to change an invisible form value under the login form.

HTML

```
      if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
             echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
          }?>
      <br />
       <form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">                      
           Email: <input class="searchform" type="text" name="email" size="20"/><br />
           Password: <input class="searchform" type="password" 
                         name="password" 
                           id="password" size="20"/><br />
          <input type="button"  class="searchform"
               value="Submit" size="40"  style="height:45px; width:90px"
               onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /> 
   <input type="text" id="errorbox" style="height:45px; width:180px" value=""><br>
   </form>
```

here's the php file:

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['p'];

      if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
      // Login success 
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('light').style.display=
      'none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display=    'none'</script>";
    } else {
      // Login failed 
      echo "<script>document.getElementById('errorbox').value='Error'</script>";
  }
  } else {
     // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
     echo 'Invalid Request';
   }
```

## I know I'm not doing this right, I'm just not sure HOW to do it at all...

Comment: Use AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: will AJAX make the login process less secure?

Comment: No, it won't, ajax is an HTTP request, in the same way that a full page reload is.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, technically you can do that, but it is a VERY bad practice, and extremely not clean.

what you'd prefer to do is use Ajax, and do those JS actions in it's success callback:

**Note: you will need to include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) lib in your scripts.**

**Another none: if you don't have PHP 5.4 on your server, just remove the second callback function, and handle all the scenarios in the success callback**

```
!(function($){
   $(function() {
         $('#submitBtn').on('submit', function(){
            $.post('process_login.php', $('form[name="login_form"]').serialize(), function(data){
              //data is a json object which contans the reponse
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              $("fade").fadeOut();
              $("light").fadeOut();
            },
            function(data){//error callback
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              if(data.forbidden){
                  $("#errorBox").html("Error!");
              }
              else if(data.error){
                $("#errorBox").html("Invalid request!");
              }
            });
          });

    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<form name="login_form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Login">
  </div>
</from>
```

PHP:

```
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['p'];

      if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
          http_response_code(200);//HTTP OK, requires php 5.4
          $response['success'] = true;

    } else {
      // Login failed 
      $response['forbidden'] = true;
      http_response_code(401);//HTTP forbidden
  }
  } else {
     // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
      $response['error'] = true;
      http_response_code(400);//HTTP bad request
   }

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: This seems like what I need to do.  I tried copying your code verbatim, (well, adding 
    <script type='text/javascript'>
and the close tag underneath my form HTML).  I still don't get anything besides "Object not found!" error 404.

I added the jquery 1.9 library, and I'm not sure what version my php is.  I'm using the updated version of xampp..

Comment: Since it's an event  handler, it should be in the jQuery ready function...
I'll edit the code

Comment: i'm getting a snytax error now on the last line.  also "'from[name="login_form"]'"  is supposed to be FORM[name...] right?  (I'm not being sarcastic, I'm just in over my head on the JS side of things)

Comment: Regarding the syntax error, I've just ran the code through js linter, had some warnings but no errors, try it now.

Comment: ugh, still getting the object not found error.  not sure where my problem is.  note: i'm not using the JS lightbox, it's css.

Comment: did you add jquery lib to you scripts?

Comment: ya, the 1.9 lib.  am i supposed to be using a standard HTML form or AJAX?  i really wish the error was more specific.

Comment: I've updated my code several times, and now it passes the most strict linter, try to copy my code again, if you are doing any changes to the code, make sure to validate the code with js linter afterwards:
http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: could the "onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"  in the form be interfering?

Comment: okay, i got it to do SOMETHING.  but it just opens process_login.php and displays {"success":true} on a blank page instead of preventing default and staying on the same page.

Comment: Well, basically calling `event.preverntDefault();` should prevent that... also added a `return flase;` statement, try it now.

Comment: still nothing.  what about stoppropagation or stopimmediatepropagation ?

Comment: Ok, on that case you can just bind this event handler to the click event of the login buton, which should be a regular button (not `type='submit'`).
edited my code

Comment: where would i add my formhash?  it's essential to the login process, and i'm fairly certain that the form.submit(); at the end of it is causing all the problems

Answer (score 0):

add onsubmit event attribute to the form: 
`<form onsubmit="return validate();">`...

where validate() is a js function that closes lightbox and returns true if form is ok, or displays errors and returns false if form is bad.